# Что значит аргумент @{u} в Git?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-merge

Например вместо `git pull` можно было использовать:

```
git fetch
git merge @{u}
```

Что здесь означает `@{u}`?

Comment: нет такого аргумента. Вы на каком-то сайте увидели и не дочитали объяснение, судя по всему.

    git merge --help 

Выдаст Вам все что принимает merge.

Comment: В книге "Git: Version Control for Everyone. Beginner's Guide" на 69 странице есть такое предложение: "As an alternative to git pull, we can also use git fetch followed by git merge @{u}".

Comment: Поиск в гугле по ключевым словам "git merge @{u}" выдает ссылку на http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/02/merge-vs-rebase/.
На этой странице тоже встречается @{u}

Comment: Так что вопрос что же означает @{u} остается в силе.

Comment: [What does the argument @{u} mean in Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474577/what-does-the-argument-u-mean-in-git/19474730#19474730)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474577/564240

Answer (score 1):

Это сокращение ссылается на ветку в удалённом репозитории, который отслеживает ваша текущая ветка. К примеру, если вы находитесь на ветке `topic/fix_blub`, которая отслеживает `origin/topic/fix_blub`, тогда `git merge @{u}` сделает тоже самое что и `git merge origin/topic/fix_blub`.

`@{u}` является частью мини-языка для выбора ревизий Git. Подробнее он описан в руководстве [**gitrevisions**(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

<sub>Это перевод ответа «[What does the argument @{u} mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474730)» с enSO.</sub>